# Brown-Forsythe using python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python

I'm analysing what's the pattern of sales of a product. For that I grouped the sales by week (1st week, 2nd week, 3rd week and 4th week). 
The sample sizes differ significantly from each other, so do the variances. For this reason I would to perform a Brown-Forsythe test.
As I'm doing this with Pyhton, I'm struggling to find a library that has provides this functionality. 
Do you know something or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in SciPy. It ostensively does not have a Brown-Forsythe test built in... but it does have a Levene test. And it takes a `centre` parameter, which lets you specify if you want to use the mean or the median.

If you use median, well, that's a Brown-Forsythe, just hidden under a different name.